# Send my current location via SMS - Android

Tags: android, url, gps, sms, location

Im a new android developer. 
I want to send a SMS which contains my current location. I know how to get my location coordinates. But what I want is send like a URL, and the User could open and see where I am(For example: With waze you can share you location and I think also with google maps app). I tried with google maps API  but I didnt find like an option to generate a URL.

Can anybody give some ideas?Or an API?

Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: if you know how to get location coordinates, then first make a link on your side, then try sending it throught sms.

Comment: But how can make that link?

Answer (score 9):

I guess this is what you need.

```
public void sendLocationSMS(String phoneNumber, Location currentLocation) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
    smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com?q="); 
    smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLatitude());
    smsBody.append(",");
    smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLongitude());
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
}
```

I would use a map overlay instead of default maps.

I have developed an app which uses the location feature and shows in map. See it on google play.

"Wherez U" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kabhos.android.apps.knowmylocation

Comment: You just need to modify the base link, like this:
smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

Comment: @hhyari can you tell me how it work if i use a string sms

Answer (score 5):

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLocation.getLatitude()+","+currentLocation.getLongitude();

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
    smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri)); `
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
```

you have to parse that string to uri. it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

refer this link
http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

after getting  it send that location using sms api .

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I know How to get my location. What I do not know is how to send a url with my location and the person who I send my location be able to open that url . For ex when the person click the Url a map display on it. Click and send to google maps with my location.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue and was not able to generate URL to be send to the receiver and I found this. Here I have a link in which we have to pass the LAT and LONG of the current location of sender and then you have to just send this link to your receiver.
https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@(latitude),(longitude),(zoom level)z
https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@-15.623037,18.388672,8z

You can also try first to open this link in your browser and then apply it to your project